# IndexError: list index out of range for text file

Tags: python-3.x

I am unable to write the first and the last line from the text file to Json file. And every alternative line is being read from the text first. Can someone help to fix this? Thank you

```
import json
filepath = 'sample.txt'
line = []
data = []
with open(filepath) as fp:
    for line in fp:

        line = fp.readline()
        print(line)
        line = line.split(',')
        #print(line)
        data= []
        data.append({
            'FileName': filepath,
            'bbox_left': line[0],
            'bbox_top': line[1],
            'bbox_width': line[2],
            'bbox_height': line[3],
            'Score': line[4],
            'Object_category': line[5],
            'Truncation': line[6],
            'Occlusion': line[7]
        })
        with open('data.json', 'a') as outfile:
            json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import json
filepath = 'sample.txt'
line = []
data = []
with open(filepath) as fp:
    line = fp.readline()
    print(line)

    while line:
        line = line.split(',')
        print(line)
        data= []
        try:
            data.append({
                'FileName': filepath,
                'bbox_left': line[0],
                'bbox_top': line[1],
                'bbox_width': line[2],
                'bbox_height': line[3],
                'Score': line[4],
                'Object_category': line[5],
                'Truncation': line[6],
                'Occlusion': line[7]
            })
            with open('data.json', 'a') as outfile:
                json.dump(data, outfile)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        line = fp.readline()
```

Comment: Nope, Exception isn't printed. Seems to be the problem in splitting and writing the string

Comment: Yes, I have fixed it too. Working for multiple text files from a single folder now. Thank you for your effort